# MD5 and Triple Des Encryption in PHP with KEY, and IV

Tags: php, json, encryption, tripledes

I have given a task to integrate our company system to external system via API. When I read about the API, it stated that the data should be encrypted using MD5 and Triple Des Encryption, so I made some research about how to do it.

```
// Here's the credentials to be used for encryption.

$key = 'dEvu4MHkqz7mRgeqmB1mQEXi';
$iv  = "avz9bUNx";
```

The data should be formatted as JSON String before encryption.

```
$params = array(
        'Number' => '+11177109886' // example
    );

$text = json_encode($params);
```

After that I made some codes to encrypt it.

```
function apiEncode($text, $key, $iv)
{
    // to append string with trailing characters as for PKCS7 padding scheme
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $padding = $block - (strlen($text) % $block);
    $text .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    return base64_encode($crypttext);
}
```

The error I got is.

> Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Received initialization vector of size 0,
>   but size 32 is required for this encryption mode in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dapsapi/rdremit.php on line 20

Comment: *"encrypted using MD5"*?!

Comment: Note that `mcrypt` is abandonware and should not be used anymore. Use a simpler library like https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium.